# Is there a way to round a decimal place to the nearest whole in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, rounding

I have a number with decimal places and I am wondering if it's possible to round the decimal to the nearest whole using javascript?

My number is: 4.59

I need my number to round to: 4.60

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Number.toFixed(number of decimal places)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = 4.59;
var rounded = num.toFixed(1);
```

Comment: Quick, simple, straight to the point. I can't believe how easy it was, I may have been thinking too hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `toFixed()` method.

More detailed information at: [MDN :: toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Please refrain linking to w3schools, they're not a representative for javascript. Link to MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: @Exelian - That seems arbitrary to me, especially for those of us who find info @ w3schools and not @ mdn (for example).  And, what exactly does 'not a representative for javascript mean'?.

Comment: I've seen another website w3fools, which also attacked this school, for errors which seem trivial (especially for a beginner). They seem to be on a crusade against them.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) outlines some rather misleading errors in w3schools. They **are** on a crusade against w3schools because they feel that they should be better. I think what Exelian meant by not being 'a representative for javascript' is that w3schools does not shape the development of javascript (unlike [w3c](http://www.w3.org/), who w3schools pretend to be, or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)).

Comment: I can't speak for the quality of w3schools lately, but I stopped using it a long time ago because I kept finding mistakes. From reading some of w3fools, it looks like they still have a lot of inaccurate/misleading information. I've also found minor mistakes in Mozilla's documentation, but it's generally pretty good.

Comment: @Spycho, actually the MDN is THE active development team behind javascript. So it makes sense to link to the actual latest docs they provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 4.5678;
Math.round(x * 10) / 10; // 4.6
Math.round(x * 100) / 100; // 4.57
```

Where the number of `0`s of multiplication and division is the decimal point you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you do what Daff suggests, but if you want the trailing "0", you will need to add it onto the string:

```
var num = 4.59;
var rounded = num.toFixed(1) + '0';
```

Also, if you want the number as a number rather than a string, use:

```
Math.round(num * 10);
```

As Emil suggested. If you then want to display it with the trailing 0, do:

```
Math.round(num * 10).toFixed(2);
```